# Update text field border using Jquery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I'm trying to build a nice contact form, from where a user can send an e-mail. I have 3 input fields (1. name, 2. e-mail address, 3. telephone number).

```
<p>
    <label for="name"><?php echo $label_name; ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="email"><?php echo $label_email; ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="tel"><?php echo $label_tel; ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" size="30" />
</p>
```

The styling of the fields is made with the following JQUERY script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').addClass("idle");
    $('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("idle").addClass("focus");
            this.select();
        });
    $('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("focus").addClass("idle");
    });
});
```

Basically what I want is to style the fields with RED border, if the server would return false (using AJAX and PHP). For this, I searched the net and tried to implement a few scripts, but none worked. Here's what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
        $.ajax({url:"php/verify_field.php", success:function(result){
            $(this).removeClass("idle").addClass(result);
        }});
    });
});
```

Thank you all for answering!

The reply of Omid Amraei seems to suit my project so far. But could we add some spice to all this script: I would like to transmit 2 parameters with the Jquery-Ajax script to the server-side PHP file:

1. the ID of the text input
2. the value of the text input.
   All this with POST method!

This way I could parse the information in the PHP file using $_POST method and check first the ID, then run the verification criteria on the value of the input.

Many thanks for all!
Happy Saturday :)

Comment: Please please don't use jQuery to style unless you absolutely have to. It's faster and more robust if you do it where these tags are generated by adding a class attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because using `this` in Ajax callback does not point to your input, so try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
        var $input = $(this);
        $.ajax({url:"php/verify_field.php", success:function(result){
            $input.removeClass("idle").addClass(result);
        }});
    });
});
```

Comment: That standard of jquery vars is prefix of `$` `input` => `$input`.

Comment: This script seems to work so far, but thanks for everybody who replied!

Answer (score 0):

`this` in this case isn't the `textbox` it's the ajax jquery object

Change the context to `this`.

```
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"php/verify_field.php",
        context: this
        success:function(result){
            $(this).removeClass("idle").addClass(result);
    }});
});
```

[**docs:**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> contextObject
>   This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to $.ajax).

Comment: `input[type="text"]` selector will return all `textboxes` and will make unexpected result. in this example we are going to just verify that special textbox.

Comment: @OmidAmraei. Right removed that option.